# Android Driver throwing error, when trying to automate

Tags: android, ruby, selenium, android-emulator, webdriver

I am trying to automate for mobile browser, using selenium (Android driver) with ruby script, 
here is sample script for same

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require "selenium/client"
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.android  
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new  
client.timeout = 480  
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(  
  :remote,  
  :url => "http://localhost:8080/wd/hub/",  
  :http_client => client,  
  :desired_capabilities => caps)  
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"  
element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')  
element.send_keys "Example google"
element.submit  
puts driver.title  
driver.quit
```

It executes the steps till `sendkeys`, step but after that, it is throwing error, captured error is

```
EOFError: end of file reached
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `read_nonblock'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:153:in `rbuf_fill'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_l
ine'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1406:in `block in transport_r
equest'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `catch'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1403:in `transport_request'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1376:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `block in request'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:1367:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:428:in `submitElement'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.35.1/lib/s
elenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:179:in `submit'
        from (irb):14
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'irb(main):015:0> puts driver.title
```

I also tried all commands in `IRB` to confirm its not due to timeout exception.
Kindly suggest, what exactly is the problem and how to get over from this kind of scenarios in mobile browser automation.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: curious - are you meaning to use a hub? or are you trying to run this locally?

Comment: I'm trying to run this locally, running it on emulator.

Comment: ok, because you are using a hub.. a hub should be a dedicated machine. I'll answer this question -

Comment: are you using HTMLUnit?

Comment: Nope, I am not using HTMLUnit, I have already posted original script and occurred error in the question. its my first script for mobile automation and I am not able to find out the reason for the error... any suggestion would be a great help \

Comment: I am in a similar situation, except I can get it to work fine in an emulator and not on a real device. Same thing, first command works, second fails with EOF error.
 (I set up my server to forward to port 8090 as I was already using port 8080)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote,:url=>'http://localhost:8090/wd/hub',:http_client=>client,:desired_capabilities=>capabilities)
driver.navigate.to 'http://www.google.co.uk'
element = driver.find_element(:name,'q')
EOFError: end of file reached
...

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the EOF error while automating against a real device and an emulator (though at different points).

The solution was to uninstall the new android-server-2.32.0.apk and install the older version android-server-2.21.0.apk.